# Можно ли передать объект в слот и взаимодействовать именно с ним, а не с копией?

Tags: qt

У меня есть объект, который я передаю в слот другого класса, а после изменяю его.

Как сделать так, чтобы он и в источнике сигнала изменился?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Передать по указателю *.

Comment: Или по ссылке &